# Advantage of "condition == $variable" style?

Tags: php, if-statement

I often see if's like:

```
if (null === $var)
```

I wanted to know wether there is any **technical** advantage by using it?

I find it semantically wrong and I don't like it. Prefer

```
if ($var === null)
```

because I ask for the condition of a variable, not for a variable having a condition.

Comment: i use $var === null .. both are correct, use the style you prefer

Comment: If this is opinion based, well, would answer my question (no, no technical advantage). But why downvote...

Comment: I think it stems from the practice of using non-lvalues on the left side of a == operator. If you accidentally use =, then most languages will throw an error about an invalid assignment, but you might miss it if the terms were switched.

Comment: I admit this is not exactly easy to google for, but it has been asked countless times. Just follow the trail of dupe closes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of conditions is sometimes referred to as [yoda conditions](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html). Their main advantage is that they avoid accidental assignment:

```
if ($foo = 'bar')
    echo 'Evaluates to true, and reassigns $foo silently';
if ('bar' = $foo)//error
```

Other than that, it's a matter of personal preference